Angular how to init RxDB in provideAppInitializer
I'm a ReactJS developer I decided to enhance my knowledge in Web Development in general it led me into diping my toe in water and trying Angular by developing an application that relies on RxDB.
I'm trying to make RxDB database accessible globally first thing I did is wrapping RxDB database inside an Angular service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createRxDatabase, RxDatabase } from 'rxdb';
import { ItemCollection, itemSchema } from '../items/items.schema';
import { getRxStorageMemory } from 'rxdb/plugins/storage-memory';

type MyDatabaseCollections = {
  items: ItemCollection;
};
type MyDatabase = RxDatabase<MyDatabaseCollections>;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DatabaseService {
  private static database: MyDatabase;

  constructor() {}

  async initDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    if (!DatabaseService.database) {
      const db = await createRxDatabase<MyDatabaseCollections>({
        name: 'mydb',
        storage: getRxStorageMemory(),
      });

      await db.addCollections({
        items: {
          schema: itemSchema,
        },
      });

      DatabaseService.database = db;
    }
  }

  getDatabase(): MyDatabase {
    if (!DatabaseService.database) {
      throw new Error('Database not initialized yet');
    }
    return DatabaseService.database;
  }
}

and inside the root app app.config.ts is where the initializing of the service happens:
  providers: [
    DatabaseService,
    provideAppInitializer(() => inject(DatabaseService).initDatabase()),
  ],

Finally inside items.component.ts which is where I'm accessing the data the earliest:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-items',
  imports: [ToastModule],
  templateUrl: './items.component.html',
})
export class ItemsComponent {
  items: ItemType[] = [];

  constructor(
    private toastService: ToastService,
    private databaseService: DatabaseService,
  ) {
    this.getItems();
  }

  getItems() {
    const db = this.databaseService.getDatabase();
    const items = db.items.find().$;

    items.subscribe((docs) => {
      console.log(docs);
    });
  }

Is returning an error:

Database not initialized yet


Can you include the decorator you use for items.component.ts ?

@MatthieuRiegler Yes, I've just updated items.component.ts

The app initialization aspect should be working correctly (here's a StackBlitz). You're double instantiating your DatabaseService (once with @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) and once by including it in your app.config.ts providers array, but that shouldn't matter since the field is static. Can you narrow this down to an Angular issue or is it possible RxDB is failing to initialize properly?

@KadiemAlqazzaz please share main.ts, do you have a main.server.ts do you have SSR enabled?
